The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services
Iam using Nuxt3 with VueFire package for connecting with firebase. Even after following the documentation in the official website iam getting the error as shown in title.
Nuxt.config.ts
  export default defineNuxtConfig({
      devtools: { enabled: true },
      modules: ["nuxt-vuefire"],  
      vuefire: {
         auth: {
         enabled: true
      },
      config: {
          apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
          authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
          databaseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
          projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
          storageBucket: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
          messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
          appId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
          measurementId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
      },    
    },
})

App.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtWelcome />
  </div>
</template>

I wanted to do Firebase Auth

You have no call to initializeApp. Did you see  the first code snippet in https://vuefire.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html#Usage?

I had looked on the below documentation which specifically tells on how to configure on nuxt. That was not telling anything about  initalizeApp
https://vuefire.vuejs.org/nuxt/getting-started.html

I have fixed the issue by adding the service-account in firebase

Thanks for the answer. Can you detail the answer please. I am still facing the issue. I am deploying with the same service-account.

To complete the previous answer by @sreerag-n-varier and to reply to @yardstick17, yes the problem is solved by adding the service-account as mentioned in the official documentation here.
In the .env file just add
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = service-account.json

Then, to get that file from Google:

Go to the Firebase console.
Navigate to Settings > Service Accounts.
Click on the button 'Generate new private key' in the section called 'Firebase Admin SDK'.
Rename the downloaded json file to service-account.json and place it alongside the .env file.
Relaunch the Nuxt server.

That solved it for me. I hope this helps.
